# JSON Schema validation patternProperties behaviour

Tags: json, regex, validation, schema

I am using JSON schema validation to validate an openapi spec. I have set property schema as below :

```
...
 "patternProperties": {
                "^[\/][a-zA-Z0-9{}]+(_[a-zA-Z0-9{}]+)?$" : {
...
```

And I have an object that looks like this :

(root).paths./{tcin}

But although I tested the regex thoroughly, I am still getting an error as :

```
----  Error 2 ----
Path : (root).paths
Message : Additional property /{tcin} is not allowed
```

Can someone point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh. Never mind. I found the error is actually a bug here : https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema/issues/74 . Its a shame. Its an awesome library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this is a bug on the application. What a shame :(. Its otherwise an awesome library but I dont know if Ill be able to fix it.

https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema/issues/74